# git pull changes to sub branch

Tags: git

I've cloned a repository called A and created a new branch called Li.
Now someone updated A's master branch and I've pulled the changes to my master branch using:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Now I want to update my branch (Li) with the changes.
How do I do it?

In adittion, after updating my local branch with the changes, I need to update the remote Li branch with the changes as well, right?
Do I do it by using:

```
git checkout Li
git push origin Li
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To merge changes from `master` in your `Li` branch, use the following commands:

```
git checkout Li
git merge master
```

You're right for pushing changes to origin, this will create a new `Li` branch on `origin`.

Comment: thanks. So pull fetches the changes from the remote repo and merges them, and merge only merge changes from one local branch to another local branch?

Answer (score 2):

you first merge branch master with branch Li

```
git checkout Li
git merge master
```

then you push the local Li branch to the remote repository

```
git push origin Li
```